# What is the best way to work on web development collaboratively?

Tags: web-development, collaboration, wordpress

What is the best way for a small team (2-3 people) to work on developing a website together?

I mostly do solo work, but I'm putting together a simple WordPress site for a university lab. Until I can secure university server space I'm working on local host using XAMMP.

I tried some free hosts as a temporary fix, but there were many issues with them. Changes I made to the CSS and themes were not reflected on refresh, but would appear some time later.

I want to make sure that we are on the same page and nobody makes changes without everyone else being aware of them, because as it stands my partner (who does not have as much experience with this realm as I do (and I dont have a lot as it is) is currently working from a crappy host and I am working offline and manually importing my work to her host.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to put your code under some sort of [distributed revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control). This can be done with software like [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29). But there are many more out there:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

(Note that distributed revision control would be best if you are working offline as well, as you mention).